# Default way to get request code in ActivityResultContract

Tags: android, android-intent, registerforactivityresult, activity-result-api

Is there any default way to get the request code in `ActivityResultContract`?

I know about `StartActivityForResult` contract, which returns `ActivityResult`, but there is no `requestCode`, only `resultCode`.

I can do something like this, but maybe there is a better solution:

```
class StartActivityForResult : ActivityResultContract<ActivityInput, ActivityOutput?>() {
    override fun createIntent(
        context: Context,
        input: ActivityInput
    ): Intent {
        return input.data.apply { putExtra(requestCodeKey, input.requestCode) }
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): ActivityOutput? {
        return if (intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) null
        else ActivityOutput(
            // should never return default value
            requestCode = intent.getIntExtra(requestCodeKey, -1),
            resultCode = resultCode,
            data = intent
        )
    }

    override fun getSynchronousResult(
        context: Context,
        input: ActivityInput?
    ): SynchronousResult<ActivityOutput?>? {
        return if (input == null) SynchronousResult(null) else null
    }

    companion object {
        const val requestCodeKey = "requestCodeKey";
    }
}
```

```
data class ActivityInput(val requestCode: Int, val data: Intent)
```

```
data class ActivityOutput(val requestCode: Int,
                          val resultCode: Int,
                          val data: Intent
)
```